# Unable to hide panels from use control in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am loading a usercontrol in a aspx page dynamically. everything is loading under update panel.

usercontrol contains around 100 panels. they are set to visible false by default(so that they won't be rendered to HTML) i am trying to set a panel visible on click of a button in aspx page. that is working perfectly. but when i am trying to set another panel from user control visible it is also showing previous panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel  runat="server" ID="pnlStandard">          
            //dynamic panels from user control loaded here
        </asp:panel>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                        class="link">test1</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
                        class="link">test2</asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you show your code you are using to show/hide the panels?

Comment: from the mark-up it seems that you are not handling the button click events individually. I am wondering how you know which panels to show and hide?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel layouts in usercontrol have sequential id. i have tored them in DB i am using `pnlStandard.FindControl('idfromdb').visible = false;` event for button click is handled individually i have written a demo code for stackoverflow. that why i forgot to mention it.

Comment: ok, well could it be that when you are handling the event from one button you are not setting the other panels visibility back to false?

Comment: @DeepakD - is it a typo that you have a closing `</panel>` tag, because that does not match the opening `<asp:Panel>` tag?

Comment: @KarlAnderson yes it is a typo i have too many line of code so intead of copying that i created a demo here.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel every time at page load,usercontrol is being loaded to panel that means all panels in usercontrol will be having their default state i.e visible="false" so i don;t have to set them visible false at aspx page code.

Comment: @DeepakD codebehind code is required to assist any further, I think there is probably an simple mistake that needs to be corrected.
breakpoint pageLoad and the code which handles the setting of the panel visibility and I am sure it will lead you to the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a reproduction of what I assume you have. I have tested this and it works as expected.

**Mark-up**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pan1" Visible="false"> 
            Panel 1
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pan2" Visible="false">
            Panel 2
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnk1" OnClick="lnk1_Click" Text="Panel1" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnk2" OnClick="lnk2_Click" Text="Panel2" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (!Page.IsPostBack)  // you do not want to handle this 
    //{                      // otherwise your panels will only hide on first load

        pan1.Visible = false; //this is required to reset the visibility of the panel back
        pan2.Visible = false; //this is required to reset the visibility of the panel back

    //}   
}

protected void lnk1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pan1.Visible = true;
}

protected void lnk2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pan2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: but why to set them visible false at load? when they already are not visible by default.

Comment: @DeepakD because as soon as one of the links is pressed the state of the panel will have changed. without changing it back in `Page_Load` it will stay visible. This is what I was trying to highlight to you.